# Apache only available over wifi

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi

I installed LAMP on my raspberry pi and i can reach the default page at localhost from the pi.  However, I can't reach the page from another computer in the LAN *unless* I'm on wifi.

If I am on ethernet, I just get a timeout.  Any ideas why?

Comment: I would bet it is a routing and/or arp problem. Network questions are better for superuser or serverfault.

Comment: Yeah I'm certain it is too, but can't figure this one out.

Comment: What’s the `Listen` line of your `httpd.conf` look like?

Comment: The listen line is simply Listen 80, which I assume is all that's necessary?